# changing the color of one cell in a datagrid after grid was startet

Tags: dojo

I have problems to change one cell of a datagrid after the grid is started. I want to change the colour of some cells and I need to ask if this cell has another value as a cell in another column, and then if this is true to change the colour.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var rows = dojo.query(".dojoxGridRow", grid.domNode);
var cellsInSecondRow = dojo.query("td", rows[1]);
var cellTwoInSecondRow = = dojo.query("td[idx='1']", rows[1]);
```

etc..

Comment: hmm okay and how can i change the colour of one cell?

Comment: dojo.style ? you have the DOMNode, so either add a css class or style property as you see fit

Comment: i´ve tried to change color with dojo.style, but there is no way to change a cell color with dojo.style